# How file to byte array converting actually works?

Tags: java, byte

I have a code to print all bytes of a File:

```
String txtDocumentName = "data.txt";
File file = new File(txtDocumentName);

byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

System.out.println("bytes.length: " +  bytes.length);

System.out.println("bytes:");

for (byte currentByte: bytes) {
    System.out.println(currentByte);
}
```

if I have a `data.txt` document content:

```
abc
```

, then it will print:

```
bytes.length: 3
bytes:
97
98
99
```

where bytes length is 3, because I have 3 characters. 97 means ASCII code of 'a' character, 98 means ASCII code of 'b' character, etc.

also, if I will have a `data.txt` document with content in russian language:

```
собака
```

, then it will print:

```
bytes.length: 12
bytes:
-47
-127
-48
-66
-48
-79
-48
-80
-48
-70
-48
-80
```

and now I didn't get what it actually does)

Can you please explain me?

***PS:*** *собака* means *dog* in english

I will be happy, if you also can explain how this trick works with image files and video files

Answer (score 2):

Text bytes are special, as one information is missing: what encoding/charset are the bytes using? In the first case some superset of ASCII. In the second case with Russian it is not a single byte encoding (otherwise the length woud be 6).

So both texts could be in UTF-8 which for every Cyrillic letter uses two bytes with high bit set (hence "negative"). This missing & associated charset one has to provide when converting from or to java's String.

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

For Russian you could write the text in Windows-1251:

```
Path cyrPath = file.toPath().resolveSibling("cp1251.txt");
Files.write(cyrPath, s, Charset.from("Windows-1251"));
```

6 Bytes, readable on a Russian Windows.

If you have purely *binary*, non-text data, never use String. As String needs always a conversion between `byte[]`, and that can go wrong (not all byte arrays are valid UTF-8).

For really binary data there are just bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same. Take into account the fact that every character is a code unit which represents Unicode code point in the UTF-16 encoding and string in its turn consists of sequence of characters. So for the russian language you got 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different coding systems that specify how a character (which is a symbol or "glyph" used in writing) should be represented as a number.

Because there are so many different characters in use around the world, not all of them can be encoded in one byte. For languages with a relatively small number of characters, one byte might be used, but the "character encoding"—the table that shows the code for a given symbol—must be specified.

Other languages, like Chinese or Japanese, use many symbols, and might [use a fixed number of bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) for each character.

If you want to be able encode any symbol from any language in one file, you can use a multi-byte encoding like [UTF-8.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) It looks like that's what is in use here. When encoded text is sent on the web, a header should specify what character encoding is used. On a file system, a file format might record that information, or the default for that system might be used. Relying on that default, or trying to guess, often leads to corrupted text.

You could read the length and decoded text from your file like this:

```
Path file = Paths.get("data.txt");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
System.out.println("bytes.length: " +  bytes.length);
System.out.println("decoded:" + new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```